# No Connection between tomcat App and the database

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a web app that in a war file and run with tomcat first i run my database with MySQL 5.7 then i run a spring boot that already made with the files after that i deploy my war file and run the app but there is no connection between the app and the database

```
function sendData(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url : link + ':3306/v1/user/login',
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : data,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response) {
            processResponse(response);
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            handleAjaxError(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax call, you're sending a request to link + ':3306/v1/user/login'.

MySQL runs by default in port 3306. 
You are running a spring-boot app in a tomcat server (that by default runs on port 8080), and your intention should be to call a service in this app to query a MySQL database.

I suggest you see this link to understand more about the problem you're facing:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/